# Tensorflow dataset splitting does not work

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I recently tried to use the `tf.data` API. I created an images dataset and has to split in into train/val/test. I'm using the below method using `ds.take` and `ds.skip` but always get train_ds correctly and no data in test_ds and val_ds.

```
DATASET_SIZE = 2000
train_size = int(0.7 * DATASET_SIZE)  # 1400
val_size   = int(0.15 * DATASET_SIZE) # 300
test_size  = int(0.15 * DATASET_SIZE) # 300
train_ds   = ds.take(train_size)
val_ds     = ds.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
test_ds    = ds.skip(train_size+val_size).take(test_size)
```

When I run the below:

```
for image, label in train_ds.take(1): 
  print("Image shape: ", image.shape)
  print("Label: ", label.numpy())
```

I see the output as:

```
Image shape:  (32, 400, 400, 3)
Label:  [39 23 21 27 28 18 28 30 28 44 34 37 21 39 35 26 48 37 41 30 22 36 46 28
 34 38 33 32 36 35 25 24]
```

But if I try to use from `test_ds.take(1)` or `val_ds.take(1)` in the above, there is no output. It seems `test_ds` and `val_ds` empty dataset. Also, when I use `val_ds` later in my `model.fit()` function, I don't see `val_loss` because of this.

I could use other techniques that would work for me but want to understand the reason/ what's wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Can you provide additional information on how you are constructing ds?

Comment: Originally I created my ds to contain filepaths (i.e., str) and labels (i.e., int64) using `ds        = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filepaths, labels))`. Then used a function `parse_function(filepath, label)` to read all images.. But it is strange when I split using `train_ds   = ds.take(1400)
val_ds     = ds.take(300)
test_ds    = ds.take(300)` it give me the required samples (but gives the same samples in all splits which I don't want).

Comment: But I would say it is not important how I created the dataset. regardless of this, see I have a dataset `ds` and I want to split it. The first function `train_ds = ds.take(train_size)` gives me perfectly a `train_ds` with samples `train_size`. But then it seems the next two splits to get `val_ds` and `test_ds` do not work. Is something wrong with `ds.skip` function or am I doing it the wrong way?